# Making a function get x values from a list. List is ok, function won't work

Tags: python

```
from math import pi, exp, sqrt

m = 0
s = 1
n = 10

min_value = m - 5*s
max_value = m + 5*s
dv = (max_value - min_value)/(n-1)
values = []
for i in range(n):
    value = min_value + i*dv
    values.append(value)

def gaussian2(values):
    for x in values:
        y = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s))*exp(-0.5*((x - m)/s)**2) # Formel
        return y
        print(y)
```

Hi, Im trying the get the function to get the x values from the table values but it won't work. I can't print the list values so there must be something wrong with my function. Any tips?

Tried this, is this a ok solution?

```
from math import pi, exp, sqrt

m = 0
s = 2
n = 10

def gaussian2(m,s,x):
        y = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s))*exp(-0.5*((x - m)/s)**2) # Formel
        return y

min_value = m - 5*s
max_value = m + 5*s
dv = (max_value - min_value)/(n-1)
values = []
for i in range(n):
    value = min_value + i*dv
    values.append(value)
print("    x    y")
for x in values:
    y = gaussian2(m,s,x)
    print("%5.1f %5.1f" % (x,y))
```

Comment: `print` is never going to be called if it's after `return`

Comment: What @DrewG. said, and since you've put a `return` in your `for` loop, it will exit after 1 iteration of the loop. Either use `yield y` or append the `y` values to a list and then return that list _after_ processing the list of values, ie after the for loop block.

Comment: You never actually call the `gaussian2` function! And if you did, it would return from the first loop iteration...

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
from math import pi, exp, sqrt

m = 0
s = 1
n = 10

min_value = m - 5*s
max_value = m + 5*s
dv = (max_value - min_value)/(n-1)
values = []
for i in range(n):
    value = min_value + i*dv
    values.append(value)

# print(values)

def gaussian2(vals, debug=True):
    if type(vals) is list:
        if debug:
            print("input len = {0}".format(len(vals)))
        y = []
        t=0
        for x in vals:
            yi = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s))*exp(-0.5*((x - m)/s)**2) # Formel
            y.append(yi)
            t+=1
            if debug:
                print("{2}: x = {0}, y = {1}".format(x,yi,t))
        return y

print(gaussian2(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the return statement in your last funciton before the print statement and inside the loop. The loop will stop running once it reaches the return statement. This modification should do the trick:

```
from math import pi, exp, sqrt

m = 0
s = 1
n = 10

min_value = m - 5*s
max_value = m + 5*s
dv = (max_value - min_value)/(n-1)
values = []
for i in range(n):
    value = min_value + i*dv
    values.append(value)

def gaussian2(values):
    for x in values:
        y = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s))*exp(-0.5*((x - m)/s)**2) # Formel
        print(y)
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution would be to do the following:

```
from math import pi, exp, sqrt

m = 0
s = 1
n = 10
min_value = m - 5*s
max_value = m + 5*s
dv = (max_value - min_value)/(n-1)


Xvalues = [min_value + i *dv for i in range(n)]
Yvalues = [1/(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s))*exp(-0.5*((x - m)/s)**2) for x in Xvalues]

for y in Yvalues :
    print(y);
```